# Why is "def InvalidArgsSpecified:" a syntax error?

Tags: python, function, syntax-error

I'm just starting to learn python... so bear with me please

Why is it giving me a Invalid Syntax error with this block of code

```
def InvalidArgsSpecified:
    print ("*** Simtho Usage ***\n")
    print ("-i Installs Local App,, include full path")
    print ("-u Uninstalls Installed App,include ID or Name")
    print ("-li Lists all installed Apps and their ID")
    print ("-all Lists All Apps in Repository")
    print ("-di Downloads and Installs App from repository, enter the title or id number")
    print ("-dw Downloads and Installs Single App from a full link")
    print ("-rmall Removes All Packages installed and removes Simtho itself\n")
    print ("*** End of Simtho Usage ***")
    sys.exit()
```

edit: Now its saying that it's undefined at line 9
Line 9 is

```
InvalidArgsSpecified()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax error is in the very first line, where you have:

```
def InvalidArgsSpecified:
```

change it to:

```
def InvalidArgsSpecified():
```

Those parentheses are mandatory in a `def`, even when there's nothing between them (just as parentheses are always used to *call* a function -- empty parentheses, in that case, if you're calling without arguments).

**Edit**: now the OP's getting an error for trying to call this function in line 9: since this function definition is more than 9 lines, it's probably getting called (from module top-level, rather than from within another function) before it's defined, in which case the simple fix is to call it only **after** it's defined.  If it's anything subtler than that, we'll need to see the code to debug it for you!-)

Comment: @Indebi, seen, and responded, though questions-with-more-than-a-question-in-them go against the grain and SO's normal behavior! If you have an error, ask a question about it, fix the error accordingly, and thereby reveal a new and completely different error, normal courteous behavior would be to accept the answer that fixed your error, and open a separate question about the new and completely different error.

Answer (score 2):

A function without arguments must still include brackets, e.g.:

```
def InvalidArgsSpecified():
```